# Is there a way to read HDMI audio on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio, hdmi

Has anyone used the HDMI adapter for receiving information on iOS? I'd like to read 7.1 audio from the HDMI cable and assign each audio channel to an audio unit (multichannel  mixer).

The adapter I'm referring to is this one: http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC953ZM/A

Thanks!

Zach

Answer (score 0):

That adapter is AV-out, I *very* much doubt you could receive anything through it.